# Can a multivariate function be assembled from bivariate functions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, graph-theory, solution-verification

Consider the three-variable case for simplicity. Can one claim that

$f(x_1, x_2, x_3) = F(g^{(12)}(x_1, x_2), g^{(13)}(x_1, x_3), g^{(23)}(x_2, x_3))$

where, for any arbitrary tri-partite function $f$, one can find bi-partite functions $g^{(12)}$, $g^{(13)}$ and $g^{(23)}$ that can reproduce $f$ via some "federating" function $F$? If so, is there a proof? Otherwise, can we find a counter-example?

- **Disclaimer:** I'm a physicist, not a mathematician, so if this question sounds too trivial, please point me to an answer and I'll be glad to close it. (My math level is that of an advanced undergraduate at best, just so you know!)
- **Context and motivation:** The context behind this question stems from the representation of "interactions" in the most general sense. One most often represents ontologies in the physical (and social) sciences as entity-relationship diagrams where the various entities are linked by (bi-partite) edges. However, most multipartite phenomena in the physical world aren't obvious "superpositions" of bi-partite edges, but rather more opaque [hyperedge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph)-like processes. (Cf. [this example](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/348091/implication-of-borns-rule-on-the-superposition-principle) for a related problem at the foundations of quantum mechanics.)

Comment: Presumably you want $F$ to be fixed? The closest result I know of is the Kolmogorov-Arnold representation theorem, although I'm not aware of any applications of it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Arnold_representation_theorem

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Could you please explain what you mean by $F$ being fixed? $F$ need not be the same for a different $f$, nor do the $g$ functions either.

Comment: But then you can take $g^{(12)}(x_1, x_2) = x_1, g^{(13)}(x_1, x_3) = x_3, g^{(23)}(x_2, x_3) = x_2$ and $F$ a permutation of $f$! The question is only interesting if you place some restrictions on what $F$ can be (by "fixed" I mean $F$ is the same for all $f$); in the Kolmogorov-Arnold theorem it is a sum of one-variable functions applied to sums of the inputs.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Right. That would clearly be a trivial workaround. Let me try and digest that Kolmogorov-Arnold theorem. That said, I take it from your answer that one *cannot* decompose a multivariate function into univariate functions?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "decompose." I interpreted the question as follows:  with given domains and codomains, is there a *single* choice of $F$ such that for *all* $f$ we can find $g_{ij}$ satisfying your equation? And then the answer is no, no single choice of $F$ will work for a sufficiently large finite set, and in fact the argument shows that on a finite set with $n \ge 4$ elements we need at least $n^3 - 3n^2$ different choices for $F$ (out of a possible $n^{n^3}$).

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified the domains or codomains, and I'm assuming you want $F$ to be fixed, so here is a simple counterargument in the "discretized" case that all of these functions are on the same finite set $X$ of cardinality $n$, say the integers $\{ 0, 1, \dots n-1 \}$.

The problem is that the number of three-variable functions $f : X^3 \to X$ is $n^{n^3}$ but the number of triples of two-variable functions $g_{12}, g_{23}, g_{31} : X^2 \to X$ is $n^{3n^2}$ and the former will be (much) bigger than the latter as soon as $n \ge 4$. Amusingly, this counting argument does suggest that we might be able to cook something up for $n = 3$, just barely, although I don't know what it would look like. The case $n = 2$ is probably small enough to do by hand.